# Even or Odd? Python in JES Program

Tags: python, if-statement, jes

Here is my code, I am having trouble getting the last IF statement to work properly, I want it to print only when the answer is not even or odd, but it prints almost every time. how should i fix it?

```
def evenOdd(x):
 for x in range (1, 6):
  num= random.randrange(1,101)
  ans=raw_input("Is" + str(num) + "Odd or Even?") 
  if (num % 2 == 0 and ans=="even") or (num % 2 == 1 and ans == "odd"):
    print "correct" 
  if (num % 2 == 0 and ans=="odd") or (num % 2==1 and ans == "even"):
    print "incorrect"
  if (num % 2 ==0 or num % 2 == 1 and ans != "odd" or ans != "even"):
    print "Please answer with Even or Odd"
```

Comment: `num % 2 ==0 or num % 2 == 1` - why would it ever get any further than that? One of those is bound to be true! Why don't you just test `if ans != "odd" and ans != "even":`, as it doesn't matter which the number is?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your last `if`, you're checking each equality individually instead of as groups.

You need to have them grouped as logical groupings. Also, I don't know why this is a function with an input that you never use. This will work for you:

```
import random
for x in range(1, 6):
    num = random.randrange(1, 101)
    ans = input("Is" + str(num) + "Odd or Even?")
    if (num % 2 == 0 and ans == "even") or (num % 2 == 1 and ans == "odd"):
        print("correct")
    if (num % 2 == 0 and ans == "odd") or (num % 2 == 1 and ans == "even"):
        print("incorrect")
    if (ans != "odd" or ans != "even"):
        print("Please answer with Even or Odd")
```

The change in the last line is because you don't actually need to check if the number is odd or even, just if the user responded with something other than `'odd'` or `'even'`.